# X and Y position of an element in relation to the browser (Note: Frames are involved)

Tags: jquery, frames

I am trying to get the X and Y coordinates of an element in relation to the browser window.

The system I am working on is made up out of various frames. I generally stay away from frames as a rule, but I am currently working on a piece of software that utilizes them quite a lot.

I am building a popup engine that needs to position a popup exactly next to a specific element. This element can be anywhere in any one of the frames at any time.

I thus need to determine the X and Y coordinates of an element in relation to the browser window, so I can place my popup next to it.

I have tried position(), offset() and even getBoundingClientRect(), but with no luck so far.

Has anyone ever tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your page is constructed similar to the following:

- Root window (i.e. browser window, #ID=ROOT)

  - Frame (frame-set or iframe, #ID=1)
  - Frame (frame-set or iframe, #ID=2)

By my understanding, you want to render the popups (tooltips perhaps?) on ROOT, but position them based on the relevant element in 1 or 2. This poses a challenge as any positioning done on ROOT would obviously be relative to the positioning of ROOT and not the sub frames. A guideline to follow perhaps could be something along the lines of:

1. Get the element's (#ID=ELEM) absolute position in relation to it's containing window.
2. Get a reference back to ROOT and execute your popup positioning in the context of ROOT.
3. Now that you're in the context of ROOT and have the absolute position of ELEM, modify the position to include the absolute position of ELEM's containing frame within the context of ROOT and render your popup at that new position.

Some code guidelines using jQuery:

```
// executing within the context of 1.2:
// get the element to which the popup relates
var ELEM = $("#ELEM");
// get the root window, i.e. ROOT
var ROOT = (function () {
    var r = window;
    while ($("#SOME-UNIQUE-ELEMENT-ON-ROOT", r).length == 0) {
        r = r.parent;
    }
    return r;
})();
// get ELEM's current absolute position in relation to 1.2
var top = ELEM.position().top;
var left = ELEM.position().left;
// get the current document's containing element in relation to ROOT
var C = $((document.parentWindow || document.defaultView).frameElement.parentNode);
// modify ELEM's position to compensate for the absolute position of C on ROOT
top += C.position().top;
left += C.position.left;
```

Now that you have the new absolute position where to render the popup on ROOT, call your rendering engine using the new "top" and "left" coordinates.

Hope that made any sense at all...